# É possível uma Closure (Swift) capturar referência da instância do objeto que a executa?

Tags: swift, instanciar-objeto, closures, swift-3, self

Estou passando uma closure para a propriedade de um objeto, e dentro da closure precisaria fazer uma referência a instância do objeto que irá executar a closure. Exemplo:

```
 typealias validator : ()->Bool

      class Field : NSObject {
         var name     : String?
         var validate : validator?
     }

     var primeiroNome       = Field()
      primeiroNome.name     = "Pedro"
      primeiroNome.validate = { ()-Bool

       // self ou uma outra referencia a instancia de primeiroNome
       return self.name != "" ? true : false

     }

    primeiroNome.validate() // Retorna true ou false
```

A solução que estou usando é usar uma closure que recebe uma instancia do tipo Field como parâmetro deste modo:

```
typealias validator : (_ instance : Field)->Bool

  class Field : NSObject {
     var name     : String?
     var validate : validator?  }

 var primeiroNome      = Field()  
 primeiroNome.name     = "Pedro"  
 primeiroNome.validate = { (instance)-Bool -> in

   // self ou uma outra referencia a instancia de primeiroNome    
   return instance.name != "" ? true : false

 }

 primeiroNome.validate(primeiroNome) // Retorna true ou false
```

A alternativa que encontrei funciona, mas gostaria de realmente poder executar a closure sem precisar passar a instância como parâmetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não.** Por quê?

***Clousures*** são *Reference Types*. Isso quer dizer que quando você declara um *clousure* a uma variável, você está declarando o tipo dela, não o valor dela. O conteúdo desse *clousure* sim será o valor da sua variável.

Exemplo:

```
var exemplo : () -> Bool = { return true }
```

Podemos ler a linha acima assim:

> *"A variável 'exemplo' é um clousure do tipo `() -> Bool` com valor booleano positivo"*

Para "capturar a referência da instância do objeto que a executa", você precisará fazer isso **através** da instância da *clousure*, ou seja, dentro do bloco.

**Dica *off-topic***: Use um *capture list* para trocar a referência *strong* do seu **self** para *weak* ou *unowned*. Isto fará com que você não crie **Strong Reference Cycles**.

Mais sobre *clousures*:

***Clousures Are Reference Types - The Swift Programming Language***
(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID104):

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o código que você colou não está completo. Mas pelo o que tu escreveste da pra fazer assim.

```
class Field {
    var name: String?
    var validate: (() -> Bool)?
}

class MyClass {
    var field: Field {
        let myField = Field()
        myField.validate = { self.field.name != nil }
        return myField
    }

    func validateField(){
        field.validate?()
    }
}

MyClass().validateField()
```